# Problem converting wma to mp3 audio

Tags: mp3, conversion, wma

When I tried to convert my audio files from WMA to MP3, I get an error message that I need to search for a plugin.  See pictures below.

How can I convert these audio files?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` or the VLC media player to convert WMA files to MP3.  Once you have VLC installed, convert your file by:

1. Open VLC and select Media -> Convert / Save
2. Add your WMA file and click Convert/Save
3. Select Audio - MP3 from the conversion drop-down
4. Choose a destination for your file
5. Click Start

With `ffmpeg`, you can convert the file from the command-line using this code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wma -ab 32 output.mp3
```

The `-b` option specifies the bitrate, so you may want to change that to fit your needs.